# Running flask in VSCode cause HTTPServer.serve_forever(self) breakpoint everytime

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, httpserver, vscode-debugger

I have created a Flask app and start to build my project, but when I use breakpoint in any file for debugging, vscode will automatically stop at this line `HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)` in flask default module.

Thing is annoying since it will jump to this line and ignore my original breakpoint, make me hard to debug.

Any idea?

launch.json

```
{
    "name": "Python: Custom Flask",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/bin/activate",
    "module": "flask",
    "env": {
        "ENV": ".local"
    },
    "args": [
    "run",
    ]
}
```

serving.py

```
def serve_forever(self):
    self.shutdown_signal = False
    try:
        HTTPServer.serve_forever(self) # <- Always stop on this line
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        self.server_close()
```

app.py

```
from flask import app
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "OK"

app.run()
```

Comment: Is there an error msg?

Comment: @CharmingRobot No, there is no error message. But, I discovered that might be normal procedure since the main thread will be running all the time and that's why stop at HTTPServer.serve_forever, so when I click other thread I can normally see the breakpoint I set in my editor. Strange thing is, I wouldn't stop at the main thread before so I have to do one more step to switch the thread which is irritating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2498

Looks like the issue is fixed in the development branch of the Python plugin and a workaround for now is

> you can continue debugging by selecting your thread in the "Call Stack" window.
>   [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2538#issuecomment-420437438)